# Find records by the most identical has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find tasks that **share the biggest quantity of same tags** to current @task.

Task.rb

```
  has_many :task_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :task_tags
```

TaskTag.rb

```
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :tag
```

Tag.rb

```
  has_many :task_tags
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_tags
```

I have it started, **task/show.html.haml:**

```
# get all tasks except current task
- Task.all.where.not(id: @task.id).each do |task| 
  # find tasks that share at least one tag
  - unless @task.tags.pluck(:id).intersection(task.tags.pluck(:id)).count.zero?  
    # display tasks with which current task shares at least one tag
    = task.id
```

How can I find:

- with which other tasks does the current task share the most tags (more efficient way?)
- sort them by `desc` (something like `same_tags_count: :desc`)?

---

Rephrasing, :

```
a = Task.first.tags.pluck(:id)
#=> [13, 25, 4, 10] 
b = Task.second.tags.pluck(:id)
#=> [13, 101] 
a.intersection(b)
#=> [13]
c = Task.third.tags.pluck(:id)
#=> [1, 2] 
a.intersection(c)
#=> []
Task.all.each do |task|
  a.intersection(task.tags.pluck(:id))
end
#=> [13], []
```

How can I find **all Tasks** that have `intersecion` with `Task.first.tags` and order them by `desc`?

Comment: Can you give a example, I am not sure what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def similiar_tasks
    self.class.joins(:tags)
              .where.not(id: id)
              .where(tags: { id: tags.ids })
              .select(
                'tasks.*',
                'COUNT(tags.*) AS tags_in_common'
              )
              .group(:id)
              .order(tags_in_common: :desc)
  end
end
```

Since its a INNER JOIN the rows must have at least one match in the joined table.

You can use `.having` to set conditions on the group:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def self.has_tags(*tags)
    joins(:tags)
      .where(tags: { id: tags})
      .group(:id)
      .having("COUNT(tags.*) >= ?", tags.length)
  end
end
```

Comment: Postgres for example doesn't let you select columns off `tags` when you apply a grouping - you can work around this by using `array_agg` and `json_agg` to get ids or names off the tags table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Max! Just what I was looking for. As long as there are such great community members as you, stackoverflow lives and thrives! ❤️